# string and numeric value when equal returns true

Tags: vba, excel

Why does 5.5 = "5.5" return true in VBA?

Is it an acceptable practice to direclty compare numeric values to string values in vba?

This returns true

```
if 5.5 = "5.5" Then ...
```

Comment: [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx)

Comment: Though, I'd love to get a canonical explanation as to *why* this happens. +1

Comment: @Raystafarian I believe it is because when a user enters a value in an Excel cell, any purely numeric value is counted as such, and not a string. To work with this VBA probably counts numeric-only 'strings' as numeric values as well.

Comment: As to the MSDN documentation: *The String is converted to a Double and numeric comparison is performed. If the String cannot be converted to Double, an InvalidCastException is thrown.*

Comment: @MaciejLos my question would be - why is this the way it's intended to function - is this similar to other languages?

Answer (score 0):

This might get shut-down as opinion-based more than anything, but I would say that YES it is acceptable. It is often used when comparing cell values to numbers, or adding cell values, for example. IE If my cells contain a string such as abcde123, and i only want to use the 123, I could only take the 3 right characters of the string and use them directly. If you want to be very rigorous you could use Cint(string) but i do not think it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like VBA converts the string to a Double and compares. From the page on [comparison operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx)

**If operands are:** One numeric and one String

**Comparison Is:** The String is converted to a Double and numeric comparison is         performed. If the String cannot be converted to Double, an InvalidCastException is thrown.